# forecasting Nelson Siegel parameters in R

Tags: r, yield, forecasting

I am working with the Nelson Siegel model from Package ‘YieldCurve’ in R. I can get the various examples in the package working fine, but I am having trouble with forecasting.

The data:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10508154/FedYieldCurve.xml

The code that gives me the parameters of the model.
    require(xts)
    require(YieldCurve)
    data(FedYieldCurve)

```
rate.Fed = first(FedYieldCurve,'5 month')

maturity.Fed <- c(3/12, 0.5, 1,2,3,5,7,10)
NSParameters <- Nelson.Siegel( rate= rate.Fed, maturity=maturity.Fed )
y <- NSrates(NSParameters[5,], maturity.Fed)
plot(maturity.Fed,rate.Fed[5,],main="Fitting Nelson-Siegel yield curve", type="o")
lines(maturity.Fed,y, col=2)
legend("topleft",legend=c("observed yield curve","fitted yield curve"),
       col=c(1,2),lty=1)
```

Specifically I can't help figuring out how to forecast the parameters with this model. Can anybody help me with this?